# An inner join with SqlAlchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a raw inner join query with counting, written directly on Postgres SQL:

```
    SELECT "films"."id" AS "megaId", 
           COUNT("filmComments"."id") AS "numOfComments" 
      FROM "films"
INNER JOIN "filmComments" 
        ON ("films"."id" = "filmComments"."filmId") 
  GROUP BY "films"."id";
```

How can I make the same, using normal SqlAlchemy, without `connection.execute(sqlCode)`?

P.S. My SqlAlchemy table classes:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Date, Float

class Film(Base):
    __tablename__ = "films"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String)
    rating = Column(Float)
    marksCount = Column(Integer)
    commentsCount = Column(Integer, index=True)


class FilmComment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "filmComments"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    filmId = Column(Integer, index=True)
    rating = Column(Integer, index=True)
    text = Column(String)
    votesUp = Column(Integer)
    votesDown = Column(Integer)
    userId = Column(Integer)
    date = Column(Date)
```

Comment: You could use the [expression API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html), or it could be [slightly different](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying) if you use the ORM. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to do it with ORM.

Answer (score 28):

Mapping that to SQLAlchemy should be quite straightforward. I'm not considering the aliases, for obvious reasons.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

megaId, numOfComments = (session.query(Film.id, func.count(FilmComment.id))
                                .join(FilmComment, Film.id == FilmComment.filmId)
                                .group_by(Film.id).first())
```

This should work. The explicit `on` clause wouldn't be needed if `FilmComment.filmId` were declared as a foreign key.

Comment: By the way, I can't test it now, so let me know if there's anything wrong.