# Converting SQL Query to SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy Flask or even Python so could anyone help me converting this sql query to sqlalchemy.

```
select Courses.course_id,Courses.course_name,Courses.section_number
  from Courses 
  join Student_courses on Courses.course_id = Student_courses.course_id 
 where Student_courses.std_id = Userid
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like:

```
session.query(Courses, Student_courses).filter( \
            Courses.course_id == Student_courses.course_id , \
            Student_courses.std_id == Userid).all()
```

One more version: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841877/an-inner-join-with-sqlalchemy)

Or [RTM](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins)