# inner joins vs joinloads in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I read about sqlalchemy `joinloads` like mentioned [here](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/55443/sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload) and I little confused about the benefits or special usages over simply joining two tables like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841877/an-inner-join-with-sqlalchemy)

I would like to know about when to use each method, currently I don't see any benefit for using `joinloads` for now, can you please explain the difference? And the use cases to prefer `joinloads`

Answer (score 10):

Sqlalchemy docs says `joinedload()` is not a replacement for `join()` and `joinedload()` doesn't affect the query result :

```
Query.join()

Query.options(joinedload())
```

Let's say if you wants to get same date that already related with data you are querying, but when you get this related data it won't change the result of the query it is like an attachment. Better to look [sqlalchemy docs joinedload](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#joined-load())

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...
    addresses = relationship('Address', backref='user')
class Address(db.Model):
    ...
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

The code below query user filter and return that user and optionally you can getting that user addresses.

```
user = db.session.query(User).options(joinedload(User.addresses)).filter(id==1).one()
```

Now lets look at join:

```
user = db.session.query(User).join(Address).filter(User.id==Address.user_id).one()
```

### Conclusion

The query with `joinedload()` get that user addresses.

Other query, query on both table, check for user id on both table, so the result depend on this. But `joinedload()` if user doesn't have any address you will have user but no address. in `join()` if user doesn't have address there will not result.

Comment: Can you please explain the part of **does not affect the query results**
with examples?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, `joinedload` is doing `left outer join` and the other join is an inner join, but I guess `joinedload` has also ability to do inner join? if so what would be the difference then?
By the way do we have an option to return the addresses in the second method?

Comment: with joinedload in any case left or inner join you will have the result if user table has user who has id = 1. But with join if user doesn't have on both table the result will be none. And yes by default joinedload() left join you can change it.

Comment: In second method if use is not none you can access the user addresses by `user.addresses`